# how to connect an aws api gateway to a private lambda function inside a vpc

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, terraform, amazon-vpc, aws-secrets-manager

I am trying to connect an aws api gateway to a lambda function residing in a VPC then retrieve the secret manager to access a database using python code with boto3. The database and vpc endpoint were created in a private subnet.

## lambda function

```
def test_secret():

    secret = "mysecret"
    region = "MY-REGION" :)
    
    session = boto3.session.Session()
    client = session.client(
        service_name="secretsmanager",
        region_name=region
    )
    secret_value_response = client.get_secret_value(SecretId=secret)

    try:
        result =  json.loads(secret_value_response["SecretString"])

    except Exception as e:
        result = "Error found: {}".format(e)
    return result


def handler(event, context):

    get_secrets = test_secret() # THE CODE FAIL HERE IN CLOUDWATCH

    try:
        some_string = event["queryStringParameters"]["some_string"]

        response = {}

        response["statusCode"] = 200
        response["body"] = some_string + " " + get_secrets["name"]

        print("secrets: ", some_string + " " + get_secrets["name"])

    except Exception as e:
        response = "Error: {}".format(e)

    return response
```

## TERRAFORM

## security group

```
resource "aws_security_group" "db" {
  name   = "db"
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.default.id

  ingress {
    from_port   = 443
    to_port     = 443
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  ingress {
    from_port   = 5432
    to_port     = 5432
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  egress {
    from_port   = 0
    to_port     = 0
    protocol    = "-1"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }
}
```

## lambda

```
resource "aws_lambda_function" "lambda_test" {
  function_name       = "lambda-test"
  ...

  # Attach Lambda to VPC
  vpc_config {
    subnet_ids = [aws_subnet.private_subnet.id]
    security_group_ids = [aws_security_group.db.id]
  }
}

resource "aws_iam_policy" "lambda_test" {
  name        = "lambda-test"

  policy = <<EOF
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "logs:CreateLogStream",
                "logs:CreateLogGroup",
                "logs:PutLogEvents",
                "ec2:DescribeSecurityGroups",
                "ec2:DescribeSubnets",
                "ec2:DescribeVpcs",
                "ec2:DescribeNetworkInterfaces",
                "ec2:CreateNetworkInterface",
                "ec2:DeleteNetworkInterface",
                "ec2:AttachNetworkInterface",
                "ec2:AssignPrivateIpAddresses",
                "ec2:UnassignPrivateIpAddresses",
                "autoscaling:CompleteLifecycleAction",
                "secretsmanager:GetSecretValue"
            ],
            "Resource": [
              "arn:aws:lambda:::${aws_lambda_function.lambda_test.arn}",
              "arn:aws:lambda:::${aws_lambda_function.lambda_test.arn}/*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "secretsmanager:GetSecretValue",
            "Resource": [
              "arn:aws:lambda:::${data.aws_secretsmanager_secret.my_secret.arn}",
              "arn:aws:lambda:::${data.aws_secretsmanager_secret.my_secret.arn}/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
EOF
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "lambda_test_role" {
  name = "lambda-test-role"

  assume_role_policy = <<EOF
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Id": "",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": [
          "lambda.amazonaws.com",
          "secretsmanager.amazonaws.com"
        ]
      },
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Sid": ""
    }
  ]
}
EOF
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "lambda_test" {
  policy_arn  = aws_iam_policy.lambda_test.arn
  role        = aws_iam_role.lambda_test_role.name
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "lambda_test_vpc_access" {
  policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole"
  role        = aws_iam_role.lambda_test_role.name
}
```

## vpc endpoint

```
resource "aws_vpc_endpoint" "vpc_endpoint" {
  vpc_id                      = aws_vpc.default.id
  service_name                = "com.amazonaws.${var.AWS_REGION}.secretsmanager"
  vpc_endpoint_type           = "Interface"

  security_group_ids          = [aws_security_group.db.id]
  private_dns_enabled         = true

  policy                      = <<EOF
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
          "Effect": "Allow",
          "Action": "*",
          "Principal": "*",
          "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
EOF
}
```

Without trying to access `secretsmanager`, the lambda itself work fine, i am able to access the url endpoint, provide parameters then see the result in cloudwatch logs but as soon as i try to call `secretsmanager` in the lambda function endpoint, the page return `{"message": "Internal server error"}` and when i look at the logs it say `{"errorMessage": "Could not connect to the endpoint URL: \"https://secretsmanager.REGIONHIDDEN.amazonaws.com/\"", "errorType": "EndpointConnectionError"`

Is there anything that i am doing wrong above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can call the Lambda function from API Gateway, then your question title "how to connect an aws api gateway to a private lambda function inside a vpc" is already complete and working.

It appears that your actual problem is simply accessing Secrets Manager from inside a Lambda function running in a VPC.

It's also strange that you are assigning a "db" security group to the Lambda function. What are the inbound/outbound rules of this Security Group?

It is entirely unclear why you created a VPC endpoint. What are we supposed to make of `service_name = "foo"`? What is service "foo"? How is this VPC endpoint related to the Lambda function in any way? If this is supposed to be a VPC endpoint for Secrets Manager, then the service name [should be](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-connect-to-aws-secrets-manager-service-within-a-virtual-private-cloud/) `"com.amazonaws.YOUR-REGION.secretsmanager"`.

If you need more help you need to edit your question to provide the following: The inbound **and** outbound rules of any relevant security groups, and the Lambda function code that is trying to call SecretsManager.

---

**Update:** After clarifications in comments and the updated question, I think the problem is you are missing any subnet assignments for the VPC Endpoint. Also, since you are adding a VPC policy with full access, you can just leave that out entirely, as the default policy is full access. I suggest changing the VPC endpoint to the following:

```
resource "aws_vpc_endpoint" "vpc_endpoint" {
  vpc_id                      = aws_vpc.default.id
  service_name                = "com.amazonaws.${var.AWS_REGION}.secretsmanager"
  vpc_endpoint_type           = "Interface"

  subnet_ids                  = [aws_subnet.private_subnet.id]
  security_group_ids          = [aws_security_group.db.id]
  private_dns_enabled         = true
}
```

---

**Update 2:** This part of your Lambda function's IAM policy is wrong:

```
       {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "secretsmanager:GetSecretValue",
            "Resource": [
              "arn:aws:lambda:::${data.aws_secretsmanager_secret.my_secret.arn}",
              "arn:aws:lambda:::${data.aws_secretsmanager_secret.my_secret.arn}/*"
            ]
        }
```

That gives the Lambda access to a secret, with an ARN of a Lambda function, which is not a valid secret ARN. It should be the following:

```
   {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "secretsmanager:GetSecretValue",
        "Resource": "${data.aws_secretsmanager_secret.my_secret.arn}"
    }
```

Also this part of your policy is messed up:

```
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "logs:CreateLogStream",
                "logs:CreateLogGroup",
                "logs:PutLogEvents",
                "ec2:DescribeSecurityGroups",
                "ec2:DescribeSubnets",
                "ec2:DescribeVpcs",
                "ec2:DescribeNetworkInterfaces",
                "ec2:CreateNetworkInterface",
                "ec2:DeleteNetworkInterface",
                "ec2:AttachNetworkInterface",
                "ec2:AssignPrivateIpAddresses",
                "ec2:UnassignPrivateIpAddresses",
                "autoscaling:CompleteLifecycleAction",
                "secretsmanager:GetSecretValue"
            ],
            "Resource": [
              "arn:aws:lambda:::${aws_lambda_function.lambda_test.arn}",
              "arn:aws:lambda:::${aws_lambda_function.lambda_test.arn}/*"
            ]
```

You are assigning this policy to a Lambda function. The resources you list in the policy are the resources the Lambda function should have access to. You don't list the Lambda function itself as the resource. I'm not sure how to fix that part of the policy, it needs to be split into multiple sections, or just replace the resource list with `"*"`.

Also when you refer to a resource's `.arn` value in Terraform, you will get the full ARN, so you shouldn't be prefixing that with anything.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Mark, i have updated the post to include the security group, the python lambda function itself and `service_name` for `aws_vpc_endpoint`. The reason `aws_vpc_endpoint` was created is to retrieve credentials from AWS Secrets Manager through AWS Lambda function, I look forward to your feedback, thanks

Comment: and you are right, it seem like my problem is actually accessing `secret_manager` from the aws lambda function....which is failing to call/reach the URL endpoint of the `aws_vpc_endpoint`

Comment: Did you just now fix the VPC endpoint service name? Or was it always like that in your actual code and you obfuscated it in your question for some unknown reason?

Comment: it was always with the correct value in the code, as the one updated above, `foo` was just a way to say 'whatever value you want to'

Comment: In the future, please don't obfuscate so many things in your question that we can't read and understand your question.

Comment: sure, my bad...

Comment: @cu__007 see my updated answer

Comment: after your update above, now it say: `{"message": "Endpoint request timed out"}`

Comment: oh i can see from cloudwatch now its a policy issue, debugging...

Comment: Did the error change? If it's still saying "timed out" that is a network access issue. If it says "access denied" that's a policy issue.

Comment: @cu__007 I just noticed the error in your policy, see my updated answer.

Comment: Mark, you are the man! It worked....thank you so much!